# How to create time slot with 2 hours interval in dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want time slot of two hour interval output like this
List timeSlots = ['8:00 AM - 10:00 AM','10:00 AM','12:00 AM',....]
is there any pub packages to get this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check below code for it.

```
void timeSlots({int start = 0,int end = 24, int hourDiff = 2}){
  List<String> slots = [];
  
  int i = 0;
  while(i <= 24){
    
    if(i< 10){
      slots.add('0$i:00 AM');
    }else if(i< 12){
      slots.add('$i:00 AM');
    }else if(i == 12){
      slots.add('$i:00 PM');
    }else if(i == 24){
      //do nothing already added 12:00AM or 00:00AM
    }else{
      slots.add('${i%12}:00 PM');
    }
    
    i = i + hourDiff;
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Flutter Package `time: ^2.1.0` and refer More by Package's Documentation.

For two Hour Interval Use

```
final Duration interval = 2.hours;
```